# Getting text from an option

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select tag I'm trying to get the text of the option I am clicking on because I want to use the text to execute some tasks:

my html file:

```
            <select name="ciao" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1631285726939_22">
               <option id="search" value="search" name="search">Giulia Totti</option>
               <option id="search" value="search" name="search">annalisa costa</option>
               <option id=" search" value="search" name="search">Isidoro Tricarico</option>
               <option id="search" value="search" name="search">Carmela Maria 
               Graziano</option>
               <option id="search" value="search" name="search">Chiara Dra</option>
               <option id="search" value="search" name="search">Tommaso Condello</option>
               <option id="search" value="search" name="search">Andrea Leoni</option>
               <option id="search" value="search" name="search">Giulia Totti</option>
               <option id="search" value="search" name="search">Adnan Al Aghawani</option>
               <option id="search" value="search" name="search">Chiara Dra</option>
               <option id="search" value="search" name="search">Serena Fossati</option>
             </select>
```

my JS file:

```
             function init() {
               var me = $(this);
               var meIndex = me.index();
               $('select').click(function() {
                     console.log($('option').text());
               })
              }

              $(document).ready(init);

              **I also tried**

              function init() {
                 var me = $(this);
                 var meIndex = me.index();
                 me.click(function() {
                 console.log(me.text());
                })
              }

               $(document).ready(init);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It *sounds like* you want to log the selected option's text to the console *when it's selected*.  That would be something like this:

```js
$('#yui_3_17_2_1_1631285726939_22').on('change', function () {
  console.log($(this).find('option:selected').text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="ciao" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1631285726939_22">
  <option id="search" value="search" name="search">Giulia Totti</option>
  <option id="search" value="search" name="search">annalisa costa</option>
  <option id="search" value="search" name="search">Isidoro Tricarico</option>
  <option id="search" value="search" name="search">Carmela Maria Graziano</option>
  <option id="search" value="search" name="search">Chiara Dra</option>
  <option id="search" value="search" name="search">Tommaso Condello</option>
  <option id="search" value="search" name="search">Andrea Leoni</option>
  <option id="search" value="search" name="search">Giulia Totti</option>
  <option id="search" value="search" name="search">Adnan Al Aghawani</option>
  <option id="search" value="search" name="search">Chiara Dra</option>
  <option id="search" value="search" name="search">Serena Fossati</option>
</select>
```

Basically you would respond to the `change` event (not the `click` event) of the `<select>` element and within that event you would find the selected `<option>` within that element and get its text.

**Please Note:** Currently your markup is *invalid*.  You have multiple elements with the same `id`.  While this doesn't cause any problems in the functionality being built *here*, it can easily cause problems in other functionality.  Always use valid HTML.  In this case you likely want to remove all of those `id="search"` attributes.

It also makes *very little sense* for all of these `<option>` elements to have the same `value`.  And *none* of them need a `name` attribute, only the form element itself needs that, which it currently has (`name="ciao"`).

Putting all that together, this makes more sense to me at least within the limited context of this code in this question:

```js
$('#yui_3_17_2_1_1631285726939_22').on('change', function () {
  console.log($(this).find('option:selected').text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="ciao" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1631285726939_22">
  <option value="0">Giulia Totti</option>
  <option value="1">annalisa costa</option>
  <option value="2">Isidoro Tricarico</option>
  <option value="3">Carmela Maria Graziano</option>
  <option value="4">Chiara Dra</option>
  <option value="5">Tommaso Condello</option>
  <option value="6">Andrea Leoni</option>
  <option value="7">Giulia Totti</option>
  <option value="8">Adnan Al Aghawani</option>
  <option value="9">Chiara Dra</option>
  <option value="10">Serena Fossati</option>
</select>
```

However, if you have other code which in some way relies on the parts which don't make sense then this change as-is could break that code.  But I *highly recommend* that you correct any such dependencies so you can correct this markup as well.

Comment: Also: `meIndex` I think may equal the select element, but `me.index()` is an odd way to look it up. Assuming `meIndex` is the same as `$('#yui_3_17_2_1_1631285726939_22')` it's the select, not the option so it has no text.